# C++ raw socket sniffer cannot capture incoming TCP packets on Windows 10

Tags: c#, python, c++, sockets, raw-sockets

Core part of code is as below.
Actually, the code is copied from https://github.com/ECToo/world-opponent-network/blob/fbb35876ae26006606d07b6297d557bd53234066/%20world-opponent-network/TitanApi/Samples/ServerTest%20-%20Copy/Sniffer/main.cpp

The code can capture UDP both incoming/outgoing packets and TCP outgoing packets, but cannot capture any TCP incoming packets on Windows10.
however, it works quite well on Windows XP.

```
sniffer = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_IP);
if (sniffer == INVALID_SOCKET) {
    printf("Failed to create raw socket.\n");
    return 1;
}

memset(&dest, 0, sizeof(dest));
memcpy(&dest.sin_addr.s_addr, local->h_addr_list[in], sizeof(dest.sin_addr.s_addr));
dest.sin_family = AF_INET;
dest.sin_port = 0;

printf("\nBinding socket to local system and port 0 ...");
if (bind(sniffer, (struct sockaddr *)&dest, sizeof(dest)) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
    printf("bind(%s) failed.\n", inet_ntoa(addr));
    return 1;
}
printf("Binding successful");
//Enable this socket with the power to sniff : SIO_RCVALL is the key Receive ALL ;)

j = 1;
printf("\nSetting socket to sniff...");
if (WSAIoctl(sniffer, SIO_RCVALL, &j, sizeof(j), 0, 0, (LPDWORD)&in, 0, 0) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
    printf("WSAIoctl() failed.\n");
    perror("Error:");
    return 1;
}
printf("Socket set.");

//Begin
printf("\nStarted Sniffing\n");
printf("Packet Capture Statistics...\n");
StartSniffing(sniffer); //Happy Sniffing

//End
closesocket(sniffer);
WSACleanup();
```

Then, I tried https://www.netresec.com/?page=RawCap which is written in C#, same result as C++ code.

At last, I tried raw socket in python, it works quite well on Win10.

```
import socket
from struct import *

host = '10.0.0.18'
# create a raw socket and bind it to the public interface
socket_protocol = socket.IPPROTO_IP
sniffer = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket_protocol)
sniffer.bind((host, 0))
# we want the IP headers included in the capture

#sniffer.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP, socket.IP_HDRINCL, 1)
sniffer.ioctl(socket.SIO_RCVALL, socket.RCVALL_ON)

while True:
    packet = sniffer.recvfrom(65565)

    #packet string from tuple
    packet = packet[0]

    #take first 20 characters for the ip header
    ip_header = packet[0:20]

    #now unpack them :)
    iph = unpack('!BBHHHBBH4s4s' , ip_header)

    version_ihl = iph[0]
    version = version_ihl >> 4
    ihl = version_ihl & 0xF

    iph_length = ihl * 4
    total_len = iph[2]
    ttl = iph[5]
    protocol = iph[6]
    s_addr = socket.inet_ntoa(iph[8]);
    d_addr = socket.inet_ntoa(iph[9]);
    if protocol == 6:
         print 'Length : ' + str(total_len) + ' Source Address : ' + str(s_addr) + ' Destination Address : ' + str(d_addr)
```

Quite strange, is there any mistake I made for the C++ code?

Comment: Silly question - have you tried to run it in elevated command line ?

Comment: @pSoLT  what do you mean ?  You cannot run c++ in command line, right ?Please check the question more carefully.

Comment: I mean running the program after you compiled the code.  Please understand the comments . You can run it with admin rights ( using elevated command line or running VS with admin rights ) or without.

Comment: hmm, I did run it with admin rights. And python code can work, C++ code not work, C# not work. This is quite strange.

Comment: They use different APIs , so it's not strange at all.  It still seems to me that system or firewall might block your program.

Comment: cool!  It works after shutdown the default firewall. Thanks pSoLT. But why the python code can work without shutdown the firewall.